# How to merge old hash with new hash, that values should be null when keys not in new hash

Tags: ruby

Assuming I got a hash of old properties from an object:

```
old = {a: 1, b: 2, c: nil}
```

Then I got a hash of new properties from user input (all keys must exists in old hash):

```
new = {a: 2}
```

Finally I want get a hash of properties to update to the object like this:

```
upd = {a: 2, b: nil, c: nil} 
# upd = {a: 2, b: nil} would be better
```

Now I use `map` to implement this:

```
upd = Hash[old.map{|x| [ x[0],new[x[0]] ] } ]
```

I tried `merge`  but  couldn't get what I want:

```
old.merge(new){|k,old,new| new} #=> {:a=>2, :b=>2, :c=>nil}
```

But I think there must be some better way of doing this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: 1. nil-lify values in old hash 2. merge with new hash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way:

```
old.merge(old) { |k,_,_| new[k] }
 #=> {a: 2, b: nil, c: nil}
```

This uses the form of the method [Hash#merge](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that takes a block. The purpose of the block is to resolve values for keys that are present in both hashes involved in the merge.

Here I am merging `old` with itself, so the value for every key in `old` is determined by the block.

An array `[key, old_value, new_value]` is passed to the block. In this case `old_value` and `new_value` are the same, but as I will not be using that value in the block, I have replaced the two corresponding block variables with the placeholder `_`.

In the block I compute the value for key `k` to be `new[k]`, which is `nil` if `new` does not have a key `k`.

This approach could also be implemented with [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (a.k.a `inject`):

```
old.reduce(old) { |h,(k,_)| h[k] = new[k]; h }
```

Comment: I want `{a: 2, b: nil, c: nil} ` instead.

Comment: I initially misunderstood the question. I believe my edit conforms.

Comment: what does `_` mean in this code? and can you plz explain me three objects which you have taken `|k,_,_|`

Comment: @HetalKunti, my apologies for not explaining before you asked. I have edited my answer to provide an explanation. Please let me know if it's not clear.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's an out-of-the-box way to do what you want, so your current solution seems OK.

You could avoid the `[0]`, by doing either:

```
upd = Hash[old.map{|k, v| [k, new[k]] }]
```

or

```
upd = Hash[old.keys.map{|k| [k, new[k]] }]
```

One caveat eith the current solution: if a key exists in `new`, but does not exist in `old`, it will not be present in `upd`. You may be aware of this, but I thought it should be pointed out.

Comment: Thanks! In my case all keys must exists in old hash. So I wasn't aware of the problem you mentioned. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
old.inject(new.dup) { |h, (k,v)| h[k] = nil unless (v.nil? || new.has_key?(k)); h }
# => {a: 2, b: nil}
```

Basically, it says to start with a copy of `new`.  Then build up the resulting hash `h` by iterating over the `(k,v)` pairs in `old`.

The only extra things we want in addition to what's in `new` is when there was a key in `old` with a non-nil value, but now the key is not present in `new` and so we want to indicate that by *having* the key in the result, but with a `nil` value.  So if `(k,v)` is a par in `old`, and `h` is the result we're building, then we want to add `h[k] = nil` if `v` was not nil, but `k` wasn't even a key in `new`.  Since there's a bunch of negations in there, it's simpler to express it with an `unless`, resulting in the form above.

Comment: It's really perfect if there are keys in the new hash not exists in the old hash. Thanks for your reply!